# ElasticSearch search_after giving incorrect results

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch

My team is using ElasticSearch 6.2 and has an index with 100,000,000 documents in it. There are 100,000 documents with a name field equal to 'Samuel'. I've written an ElasticSearch query to retrieve all documents that have the name field equal to 'Samuel'. I am using the unique field of id as the sort field:

```html
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "match": {
          "name": "company"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "id": "asc"
    }
  ]
}
```

When I run this query, ElasticSearch gives me the following response:

```html
{
  "took": 54,
  . . .
  "hits": {
    "total": 100000,
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": [
    . . .
    ]
  }
}
```

I want to paginate through all 100,000 of these results. From what I understand, there are two ways of doing this:

- Option 1: Use the from and size parameters and add them to the query.

```html
{
  "from": <FROM>,
  "size": <SIZE>,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "match": {
          "name": "company"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "id": "asc"
    }
  ]
}
```

- Option 2: Use the search_after parameter and include the id from the hit of the last page.

```html
{
  "search_after": [<ID>],
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "match": {
          "name": "company"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "id": "asc"
    }
  ]
}
```

Using option 1, while it takes a lot more calls, is returning all 100,000 results I'm expecting. However, I am finding that option 2 is giving me A LOT more results then the expected 100,000. It also seems to be returning documents that don't meet my criteria. The first page (without using search_after) is returning the results I expect. Any idea why search_after might be returning incorrect results?

Comment: Any chance you can upgrade to a version of elasticsearch that didn't EOL?

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not an option at this time.

Comment: The reason I am asking is because it sounds like a bug, but it is most likely fixed with with point-in-time search, so I wouldn't even suggest reporting it since nobody will look at it.

Answer (score 0):

If upgrade is not an option, I would suggest switching to [scroll](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/search-request-scroll.html) instead. It was a more solid solution around 6.x timeframe.